# Finding a distribution satisfying uncountably many constraints: a follow up in a more restrictive setting

Tags: pr.probability, nonlinear-optimization

Recently, I posted the question [Finding a distribution satisfying uncountably many constraints. Any relevant references?](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/342485/finding-a-distribution-satisfying-uncountably-many-constraints-any-relevant-ref). Bjørn Kjos-Hanssen quickly and astutely pointed out that without further assumptions, a solution is not tenable. A more restrictive formulation introducing a continuity assumption is as follows:

Let $X$ be some uncountable set, and $Y = {0,1}$. Suppose $f: X \times Y \to [0,1]$, and $f(x, 1): X \to [0,1]$ is continuous; given $\mathcal{H} \subseteq Y^X$, find $P$, a distribution with support on $\mathcal{H}$, such that

$$
\forall x, \ f(x, y) = \int_{h\in \mathcal{H}: \  h(x) = y}dP(h),
$$

assuming it exists.

If anyone has any references they think might be useful in solving this, or further input on why it may not be worth the time to think about it further, I would be very grateful.